# Exchange emails to pdf

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I need to export all emails (to pdf files) from some accounts in my exchange server. I have read in google search, that there is no builtin solution. Can someone tell me if there is a solution? What I have is this script, that I am trying to know how it works:

```
# Get path to wkhtmltopdf.exe
$ExePath = Join-Path -Path (
    Split-Path -Path $Script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
) -ChildPath 'wkhtmltopdf.exe'

# Set PDF path
$OutFile = Join-Path -Path 'c:\path\to\emails' -ChildPath ($Email.Subject + '.pdf')

# Convert HTML string to PDF file
$ret = $Email.HTMLBody | & $ExePath @('--quiet', '-', $OutFile) 2>&1

# Check for errors
if ($LASTEXITCODE) {
    Write-Error $ret
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. But i am trying to know if there is a c# solution too.